# Why is @autowiring field null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have a RedisConfig like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@ComponentScan("com.where.redis.config.is")
public class RedisConfig {

    /**
     * Lettuce Connection Factory
     * 
     * @return Lettuce Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED).build();

        String host = System.getenv("REDIS_HOST") != null ? System.getenv("REDIS_HOST")
                : "localhost";
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host,
                6379);

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Redis Template
     * 
     * @return redisTemplate
     */
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object,Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Redis String Template
     * 
     * @return redisStringTemplate redis String Template
     */
    @Bean(name = "redisStringTemplate")
    @Primary
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisStringTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisStringTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisStringTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        JdkSerializationRedisSerializer jdkSerializationRedisSerializer 
            = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer();
        RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        redisStringTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        redisStringTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
        redisStringTemplate.setValueSerializer(jdkSerializationRedisSerializer);
        redisStringTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jdkSerializationRedisSerializer);
        redisStringTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisStringTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisStringTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Configure Redis Action
     * 
     * @return Redis Configure Action
     */
    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to use it in a class like this:

```
public class Someclass {

    private static Long TIMEOUT = 60L;

     /** Inject the actual template */
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisStringTemplate;

    /**
     * Stores a User in redis. 
     * 
     * @param user Exavault User
     */
    private void cacheUser(ExavaultUser user) {

        redisStringTemplate.expire(REDIS_KEY, TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        redisStringTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        redisStringTemplate.opsForHash().put(REDIS_KEY, user.getUsername(), 
                user.getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

I start the app as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.where.all.java.code.is")
public class SchedulingTasksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = 
                SpringApplication.run(SchedulingTasksApplication.class, args);      
    }   
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you cannot use Autowire on any class which is not managed by Spring. for e.g Someclass is not damaged by Spring.

Comment: @dassum Ah ok, then what do I need to do?

Comment: annotate Someclass as Component or Service. Also, ensure Someclass package is in the component scan package.

Comment: @dassum Already tried that, still same result.

Comment: share the SpringBoot application class and package structure of your project along with pom.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class in which you want to use @Autowired does not have a Spring annotation. Add one of the following annotatons to the class: @Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller, @Configuration.

Also, The package is must be inside the ComponentScan search path. Move the package to a scanned location or configure the ComponentScan to fix this.

```
@Component
public class Someclass {

    private static Long TIMEOUT = 60L;

     /** Inject the actual template */
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisStringTemplate;

    /**
     * Stores a User in redis. 
     * 
     * @param user Exavault User
     */
    private void cacheUser(ExavaultUser user) {

        redisStringTemplate.expire(REDIS_KEY, TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        redisStringTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        redisStringTemplate.opsForHash().put(REDIS_KEY, user.getUsername(), 
                user.getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

Also, @dassum has added comment for the same.

Comment: You are right, one of the classes were not attached to SpringBoot